# How to make whole table cell clickable but vertical align text inside it - CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How to make whole table cell clickable but vertical align text inside it.

Alright it is achievable by making link display:block and setting line height.

But the problem is text may get 2 lines some times. So this way is not solution. Are there any other solution ?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by adding a class to the cell you want to click and hooking this up using jquery such as

```
<td class="clickable">...</td>
```

your jquery...

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
   alert('Table cell has been clicked');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do that but I usually need each cell to do something different or to send a different piece of data for each cell. So I use something like this.

```
<td onclick="update_calendar(1337317200);">19</td>
```